# Retrieving Objects from Firebase using Value() Method

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I cant figure out how to get "value" to read the data in my FB object the same way that the "child_added" does.
The following code:

```
  postNotes.on("value", function(snapshot){
  console.log("VALUE FUNCTION REACHED")
  var note = snapshot.val();
  console.log(note.noteObject);
});

postNotes.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
  console.log("CHILDADDED FUNCTION REACHED");
  var note = snapshot.val();
  console.log(note.noteObject);

}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

...displays this in the console:
[image]

And here is the data in the FB console:
[image]

I don't use any libraries. I would simply like the data from FB to display when my page loads, and continue to update each time new data is pushed to the FBDB.

Am I missing the point of the "value" parameter? What can I do better? [image]

Please forego the answers that involve things such as "read the docs", "use jquery", or otherwise useless answers some StackO users seem to be so fond of.
I've been digging around this problem of mine for a few hours and based on what else I see in StackO a few others have had a similar issue. Thank you so much for taking a look at my question and lending any insight you may have.

Comment: Downvoted in 10 minutes with no comment as to why, I'm sure what was fulfilling to someone.

Comment: Most likely downvoters felt it could have been unraveled by using `console.log(note)` instead of `note.noteObject`--a common next step in debugging--revealing a larger data set than you expected. Additionally, the [API doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) or [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html) would explained the return value of `value`. Thus, downvoters probably felt that you could have done a minute more research and had a solution. Note that downvotes may just mean the question is not useful *to others*, not necessarily a rebuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the same `postsRef` to listen to both `value` and `child_added` events. This is not a common use patterns.

The `value` event fires when the value of the node changes. So whenever *the parent node* of `-J....NI3` changes, the entire *parent* node is passed into your callback as the `snapshot`. If you check the data in the Firebase dashboard, you'll see that this *parent* node does not have a `noteObject` child.

Compare that to the `child_added` event, which fires when a *child node is added* to the node on which you listen. The callback to `child_added` in that case gets the new child node passed as its `snapshot`. And the new child node indeed has a `noteObject` child.

You'll normally listen to `value` events on single, lowest-level nodes. When you have a collection of nodes (like you do here), you'll usually use `child_added` (and its `_changed`, `_deleted` and `_moved` brethren). But just in case you really want to use `on('value'` with a collection:

```
postNotes.on('value', function(notesSnapshot) {
    notesSnapshot.forEach(function(noteSnapshot) {
        console.log(noteSnapshot.val());
    });
});
```

Just be aware that such an approach is less efficient than listening to the various `child_` events, especially as you dynamically add or change children in the collection.

Comment: Efficiency here is a tricky concept. It is more efficient, idiomatic, and elegant, in the sense that each child can be processed asynchronously, and in the sense that after the initial download, only updates are going to be sent back and forth. However, for the initial download, the same amount of data is transferred from the server in the same manner (in one bulk receipt), so it doesn't reduce memory usage by sending records one at a time or anything of that nature, until after the initial sync of the remote data.